# Querying database for existing username with Zend and doctrine

Tags: database, zend-framework, doctrine

I am querying database records to check if a username already exists this way:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->from('Tcc_Model_User u')
        ->where('u.Username = ?', $input['Username']);

 $object = $q->fetchOne();

  if(is_object($object)) {

  // not sure what to do here

 } else {

 // ok to record
```

What I cannot make it work is how to show a message that username is already taken next to the Username field of the submitted form. Could please anyone help me? Really appreciated any help. Thank you

EDITED:

Thanks to Drew010 I solved the above problem by adding:

```
 $form->getElement('Username')->addError('Sorry, that username is already taken!');
```

in the first of the conditional statement. Thank again drew010.

Comment: Are you using Zend_Form for this as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Zend_Form, there is a validator that can do this for you.

See [Zend_Validate_DbNoRecordExists](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.Db)

They give an example for validating that a given username does not exist in the database.

Here is an example from one of my applications, the third validator checks that the username does not already exist:

```
    $this->addElement('text', 'username', array(
        'label' => 'User Name:',
        'required' => true,
        'validators' => array('NotEmpty'),
        'decorators' => $this->elementDecorators,
        'validators' => array(
            array('StringLength', true, array('min' => 4,
                'messages' => array(
                    Zend_Validate_StringLength::TOO_SHORT =>
                    'Account username must be at least %min% characters'
                )
            )),
            array('Regex', true, array('pattern' => '/^\w(?:[\w\d\.\-_]+)(?:\w|\d)$/',
                'messages' => array(
                    Zend_Validate_Regex::NOT_MATCH =>
                    "The username contained invalid characters"
                )
            )),
            array('Db_NoRecordExists', true, array(
                'table' => 'accounts', 'field' => 'username',
                'messages' => array(
                    Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists::ERROR_RECORD_FOUND =>
                    "An account with the username '%value%' is already registered"
                )
            ))
        )
    ));
```

Also, for future reference, if you do extended validation you can't do with a validator, you can add an error to a specific form element like this:

```
if ($something_was_wrong) {
    $form->getElement('username')
         ->addError('Username already exists!');
}
```

Comment: Hi Drew010. Just a question: will this work using doctrine? Sorry if the question is silly!!

Comment: That will look for a default DB adapter, so you might need to set up your connection using Zend_Db as well, or run the select and then manually add the error to the form element as shown above.  Sorry, never used Doctrine with ZF so I don't know how it works.

Comment: I think the second code snippet is what you want then, it will add an error to the username element, and mark the form as having errors.

Comment: I haven't been able to pass the error from the Doctrine query to the form. Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you post more code and what you tried?  You are running that query from your controller that processes the form right?

Comment: the controller is as in my question above. I am trying to use an helper that should show the error message but it doesn't appear in the submitted form.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4732/discussion-between-drew010-and-francesco-sergio-flore)

Answer (score 0):

I would create a separate Doctrine-based validator modeled on the `Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists` validator and add that validator directly to the element

The validator:

```
class My_Validate_UsernameAvailable extends Zend_Validate_Abstract
    implements Zend_Validate_Interface
{
    const NOT_AVAILABLE = 'usernameAvailableNot';

    protected $_messageTemplates = array(
        self::NOT_AVAILABLE => "Username is not available",
    );

    public function isValid($value)
    {
        $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from('Tcc_Model_User u')
            ->where('u.Username = ?', $value);

        if ($q->fetchOne()){
            $this->_error(self::NOT_AVAILABLE);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Then in the form, attached to the username element:

```
'validators' => array(
    // your other valiadators
    array(new My_Validate_UsernameAvailable(), true),
),
```

Then there is no extra handling required in the controller.

Comment: Hi David, that you for this. I have edit my question adding the solution that Drew010 proposed. It works perfectly.

Comment: Indeed, I can see that Drew's answer will work, that he worked with you via chat, and that you have already accepted his answer. But I wanted to add another alternative that might be useful for others, since it creates a re-usable validator that is usable directly in the form, keeping the controller lean. Cheers!